# solution for Gradle build failed with unknown error?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, gradlew

i'm trying to build react native app using the eas-cli with this command :

```
eas build -p android --non-interactive --profile preview
```

but i'm getting bunch of errors

`Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.`

and this is the "Run gradlew" logs

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XnikWFu0I5Fm9a9rzKhj1KeVJz3CSNR7/view?usp=sharing

and this is the eas.json

```js
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.47.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Excerpt from the error:

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.b: Type org.reactnative.maskedview.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/android/build/.transforms/646961c1fa196d065056282afbdba2f7/transformed/classes/classes.dex, /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-masked-view/masked-view/android/build/.transforms/e99db7b68660c8211bed9c260430e726/transformed/classes/classes.dex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that **org.reactnative.maskedview.BuildConfig** is defined multiple times:

- at `/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view/android/build/.transforms/646961c1fa196d065056282afbdba2f7/transformed/classes/classes.dex`
- at `/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-masked-view/masked-view/android/build/.transforms/e99db7b68660c8211bed9c260430e726/transformed/classes/classes.dex`

You will need to look at what dependencies you have and make some fixes. This topic was discussed at GitHub as well: https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues/277

[image]

You likely have a different, but somewhat similar dependency issue.

Comment: thanks a million for this, really appreciate it, you don't know how much this means to me